# react-select.js Multi select preventDefault x button or remove

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Hy I'm using react-select for multi selection. I wish to preventDefault on remove the close option generated by the package.See attached print screen

[dead image](http://i65.tinypic.com/23wlkhz.jpg)

```js
    function renderer(obj, index){
      return <span name='name'>{obj.value}</span>
    }
    export default  class Select extends Component {
      componentDidMount(){
        this.refs.stateSelect.focus();
      }

      render() {
       const {props} = this;
       const options = props.options;

       return <Select
        {...props}
        allowCreate={true}
        multi={true}
        ref="stateSelect"
        tabIndex={0}
        autofocus
        valueKey='value'
        clearable={false}
        value={props.value}
        options={options}
        valueRenderer = {renderer}
        optionRenderer={renderer}
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />;
    }

     onChange(value, selectedOptions){
       this.props.onSelect && this.props.onSelect(selectedOptions);
     }
    }
```

Comment: You mean you wish the remove button to not remove and do something of your choosing, or just call preventDefault and still remove?

Comment: The best solution would be when clicks on the close (x) to override the default function. example function onRemove(event){preventDefault;alert('do Other thing')}

Comment: solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72603397/2761641

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible with the Select control at the moment unless you want to fork the code and modify it.

One non-elegant solution would be that in the onChange listener, compare the new value with the previous value and if some items are less, then restore the old value. If in your use case, you want to let the user clear the entire list, but not one value at a time, you can have the onChange accept the new value if it is empty.
Something like this -

```
export default  class Select extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.refs.stateSelect.focus();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    this.setState({"value":newProps.value}});
  }

  render() {
   const {props} = this;
   const options = props.options;

   return 
   (<Select
    {...props}
    allowCreate={true}
    multi={true}
    ref="stateSelect"
    tabIndex={0}
    autofocus
    valueKey='value'
    clearable={false}
    value={this.state.value}
    options={options}
    valueRenderer = {renderer}
    optionRenderer={renderer}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    />);
}

 onChange(value, selectedOptions){
    if (this.value.length > this.state.value.length
        || this.value == "" //comment this line if you don't want user to clear the entire select
        ){
      this.setState({"value":value});
    }
   this.props.onSelect && this.props.onSelect(selectedOptions);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use style value `multiValueRemove` to achieve it

```
const selectStyle = {
  multiValueRemove: (style, state) => {
    console.log('multi value remove', state, style);
    return {
      ...style,
      ...(state.data?.isDisabled
        ? {
            visibility: 'hidden',
            width: '4px',
          }
        : {}),
    };
  },

};

return <Select styles={selectStyle} />
```

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to completely remove the "x" ("clear all") button, it seems to be different to the other answers, it may have changed in new versions.
The solution below uses: `"react-select": "^5.2.1",`

The prop `isClearable` can now be used; if not supplied it defaults to `true` if
([Docs](https://react-select.com/props#statemanager-props))

> Is the select value clearable

```js
<Select
  isDisabled={isDisabled}
  isMulti={isMulti}
  options={options}
  value={value ? value : null}
  menuPlacement="auto"
  // ... 
  isClearable={false}
/>
```

Adding `isClearable={false}` will remove that "x" ("clear all") button (see the second Select in the image below)

[image]