# Is there anyway to disable the "x" that delete a selected option in react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-select

I'm Working with react-select and I need to disable the option to delete specific selections (hide or delete the x which is in the red square)

[image: I need to hide this x's]

I have looking for a prop to do it and I found this:

```
isClearable={false}
```

But that option hide this:

[image: I need to keep this x]

In summary I need to hide the x's shown at first image but keep the shown in the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this way with know the class name for the `x` and hide it with CSS

1- open the console in the browser and use the select tools

[image]

and then use the class name in CSS as this way

```
className {

display: none !important;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `multiValueRemove` as

```
const selectStyle = {
  multiValueRemove: (style, state) => {
    console.log('multi value remove', state, style);
    return {
      ...style,
      ...(state.data?.isDisabled
        ? {
            visibility: 'hidden',
            width: '4px',
          }
        : {}),
    };
  },

};

return <Select styles={selectStyle} />
```